# Manually enable 64-bit related warnings in XCode 5?

Tags: 64-bit, xcode5

What are the relevant settings in XCode 5 to generate warnings for a Static Cocoa Touch Framework that is intended to be compiled for 64 bit architectures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your build settings, you'll find the "Apple LLVM 5.0 - Warnings - All Languages" heading, underneath that you'll find many  warnings for conversions. One of the most important here is "`Implicit Conversion to 32-bit type`", which should be set to YES. `Implicit Integer to Pointer Conversions` should be set to YES. There may be others, but these are the main ones.